(VR Pico) Полноэкранный режим в приложении
Я пытаюсь адаптировать приложение к VR. Проблема заключается в том что приложение открывается в окне (В общем, как и обычные приложения). Я пытался добавить эти строки OpenXR в AndroidManifest.xml:
<meta-data android:name="pvr.app.type" android:value="vr" /> <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking"
    android:required="true"
    android:version="1" /> <meta-data android:name="pvr.sdk.version" android:value="OpenXR" />

Но приложение не запускается.
Я думаю можно обойтись и без XR.
